# Filter payload that passes to the transformer in Webservice Proxy pattern in Mule ESB

Tags: web-services, proxy, mule, transformer-model

When using a web service proxy pattern in Mule, you have the ability to pass the message through 1 or more transformers.  Is there anyway to avoid passing ?Wsdl gets or other messages filtered on Content-Type for example?  My transformer is manipulating the XML payload prior to passing it off to the web service, but I've found my wsdl calls are also being processed by the transformer and failing.

I've put a check in my transformer code, but this doesn't seem like the right way to go about solving this.

```
if(message.getOriginalPayload().toString().endsWith("wsdl")||!(xmlString.startsWith("<") && xmlString.endsWith(">"))){return message; }
```

The Proxy config:

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="SR-Proxy" 
    doc:name="SR-Proxy" 
    transformer-refs="enrichPayloadWithSFSession" 
    wsdlFile="service/SR_Webservice.wsdl">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${http.port}" path="service/SRProxy" doc:name="HTTP" />
<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="${sfdc.wsUrl}SR_Webservice" />
</pattern:web-service-proxy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `http.query.string` inbound message property to detect the `?wsdl` request.

See http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-HTTPProperties for more information about the available inbound properties you can find in inbound HTTP messages.

Comment: Thanks as always David!  I appreciate all of your help.  So validating the message inside the transformer is the correct method?  There isn't a way to filter the message before it gets passed into the transformer when using the proxy pattern?

Comment: It is not really correct to use a transformer to validate a message. In your case, the correct approach would require to build a proxy using a `flow` and use a `filter` in it. That's more work though so... the transformer can do it :)